# behave like a "cat" linux command using io/ioutil

Tags: go, input, io

have a task to creat a go file, which bahaves like cat command. I have some ideas how to do it, but i don't know how to read input if no file names written.

```
student@ubuntu:~/div-01/cat$ go build cat.go
student@ubuntu:~/div-01/cat$ ./cat
Hello
Hello
^C
student@ubuntu:~/div-01/cat$
```

Also i can use only **ioutil, io, os** packages and one of schools packages to print output.
In internet found this, but it just saves all input in *data* and then, after I press ctrl+C it prints it back.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var lenght int
    args := os.Args[1:]
    for i := range args {
        lenght++
        i++
    }
    if lenght == 0 {
        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Println(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what *you* have tried to implement `cat`. Does it work? If not, what does not work?

Comment: "it just saves all input in data and then, after I press ctrl+C it prints it back." That's what `cat` does if it reads from STDIN which you type to. What do you expect instead?

Comment: when you type just a `cat` in command line it will instantly print back whatever you type. the funcs you written first read and saves all i typed and only after ctrl+C it prints all at ones.

Comment: For *copying* (hint, hint) from os.Stdin you do not need the ioutil package. Also, I very highly doubt you're not allowed to use built-in functions (you didn't get explicit permission to use the `==` and `++` operators either).

Comment: well, I started coding just a month ago and I don't know all of them, but I can use ++ == etc. cannot use len, make, append and mb smthing else

Answer (score 0):

To check the number of arguments, use `len`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // No arguments give, read from STDIN.
    if len(os.Args) == 1 {
        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
        if err != nil {
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s", data)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    // TODO Read the content of all files.
}
```

Comment: I cannot use len, but I know about it. and i tried only what i written.

Comment: `len` is not a package, it is a [built-in function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity).

Comment: okay, still i cannot use it in my task. and your func gives the same result

Comment: Which [built-in function](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Built-in_functions) *can* you use?

Comment: i can use only ioutil, io, os and casting

Answer (score 0):

well, I found this and it works

```
if len(os.Args) == 1 {
    _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("^C")
}
```